# Can I deploy 2 different react apps on subdomains AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have 2 different apps. One is the landing page and the other one is a dashboard. I want to do something like this

dashboard.domain.com - Dashboard
domain.com - Landing Page

I want to do this on AWS. Thank you.

Comment: If you are using CloudFront, you could check the host in the viewer request and get the respective resource from the S3 origin.

Answer (score 0):

Your have 2 options.

1. Use your DNS to point dashboard.domain.com to one app and domain.com to another app. This would mean having 2 different DNS records. If you are using Route 53 read this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-routing-traffic-for-subdomains.html
2. Use your DNS to route everything to one CloudFront instance, and then have cloudfront route to 2 different origins. This would typically be done by path though. For example domain.com/dashboard or domain.com. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOrigin